# PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.61

Tags: mysql

After asking last question about $id=$_GET['id']; and security issues I tried a PDO connection to my server. The following message appeared; ERROR: could not find driver.

I connected to phpMyAdmin - 2.11.1.2 and had this message appear;
Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.61. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

Is there a connection? Are PDO drivers required on the server? Would MySqli work?

Bob

Comment: You will need to enable the `php_pdo_mysql` module in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a connection otherwise phpmyadmin wouldnt know what version the server is.

In most cases you can ignore that as only slight differences exist (for a full difference check the changelogs between the versions)

```
apt-get install php5-mysql

yum install php5-mysql
```

one of those should update your php library and not show that warning

Comment: OK.. Thank you...I have no control over this. I would have to ask the web_server people to do the upgrade and unless I have a real good reason they would not. So the question is will PDO and or MySqli work on this server or am I stuck with deprecated old code?

Comment: its not that old, There are newer versions yes, but not "old" pdo and mysqli will work though

Comment: MySQL 5.5 was released in 2009 and obsoleted MySQL 5.1 which was released in 2005. The machine you're on is as much a museum if it still has a 5.0 install on it.

Comment: @tadman - tahst his php version. The MySQL version is still current on debian squeeze

Comment: @user1281385 If Debian is shipping with MySQL 5.1 then it's in sad shape. MySQL 5.5 is significantly faster.

Comment: Its also less "tested"